# Optimizing portfolio for sharpe ratio using python scipy's optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimization

I am trying to optimize a portfolio for sharpe ratio and following is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

def get_path(sym, base_dir = "data"):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, base_dir, sym)
    return path


def prepare_data(files, dates):
    """Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
    dfstocks = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    if 'NIFTY.csv' not in files:
        files.insert(0, 'NIFTY.csv')

    for f in files:
        # TODO: Read and join data for each symbol
        files_path = get_path(f)
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(files_path, index_col = "Date", 
                              parse_dates = True,
                              usecols = ['Date', 'Close Price'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns = {'Close Price' : f})
        dfstocks = dfstocks.join(df_temp, how = 'inner')

    return dfstocks


def write_data(data, outfile):
    base_dir = "data"
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, base_dir, outfile)
    data.to_csv(path)


def get_data(filename):
    base_dir = "data"
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, base_dir, filename)
    dfstocks = pd.read_csv(path, index_col = "Unnamed: 0")
    del dfstocks['NIFTY.csv']
    return dfstocks    


def portfolio_analysis(data, alloc, init_cap, risk_free_annual):
    data_norm = data.divide(data.iloc[0])
    data_alloc = data_norm * alloc
    data_position = data_alloc * init_cap
    portfolio_value = data_position.sum(axis = 1)
    daily_returns = portfolio_value - portfolio_value[0]
    daily_returns = daily_returns[1:]

    risk_free_daily = np.power((risk_free_annual + 1), 1.0/252) - 1

    cum_return = (portfolio_value[-1]/portfolio_value[0]) - 1
    avg_day_return = daily_returns.mean()
    std_day_return = daily_returns.std()
    sharpe_ratio = (daily_returns - risk_free_daily).mean()/std_day_return
    annualized_sharpe_ratio = np.power(252, 0.5) * sharpe_ratio

    return (annualized_sharpe_ratio * -1)


def sharpe(alloc, data):
    risk_free_annual_return = 0.08
    initial_capital = 307267
    return portfolio_analysis(data, alloc, initial_capital, risk_free_annual_return)

def analyze():

    files = ["NIFTY.csv", "AGARIND.csv", "AIFL.csv", "EMMBI.csv", "IGL.csv", "JAMNAAUTO.csv", "KPRMILL.csv"]

    start_date = '12/1/2015'
    end_date = '9/21/2017'
    dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

    dfstocks = prepare_data(files, dates)
    write_data(dfstocks, 'ClosePriceAll.csv')

    filename = "ClosePriceAll.csv"
    dfstocks = get_data(filename)
    risk_free_annual_return = 0.08
    initial_capital = 307267
    allocation = [0.148, 0.112, 0.218, 0.184, 0.195, 0.143]
    portfolio_analysis(dfstocks, allocation, initial_capital, risk_free_annual_return)
    res = spo.minimize(sharpe, allocation, args = [dfstocks], method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp' : True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    analyze()
```

And this code runs in error, and following is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c3e09b18fc12> in <module>()
     95 
     96 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 97     analyze()
     98 

<ipython-input-7-c3e09b18fc12> in analyze()
     91     allocation = [0.148, 0.112, 0.218, 0.184, 0.195, 0.143]
     92     portfolio_analysis(dfstocks, allocation, initial_capital, risk_free_annual_return)
---> 93     res = spo.minimize(sharpe, allocation, args = [dfstocks], method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp' : True})
     94     #print res
     95 

C:\Users\viupadhy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.pyc in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    456     elif meth == 'slsqp':
    457         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 458                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    459     elif meth == 'dogleg':
    460         return _minimize_dogleg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess,

C:\Users\viupadhy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.pyc in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, 
bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    368                 fx = float(np.asarray(func(x)))
    369             except:
--> 370                 raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")
    371             # Compute the constraints
    372             if cons['eq']:

ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar
```

Can you help solving the problem?? 
Specific questions can be is the call to minimizer is correct?
If I have used the args parameter correctly?
What is the meaning of this error message "ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar"?
Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: it needs a scalar objective, while you got something else (vector, matrix, tuple, ...). Add some prints for debugging; ```portfolio_analysis``` is the culprit. If you are not able to do so, i highly highly recommend editing this to some minimal-example which we can run!

Comment: hey @sascha I added the following line in `protfolio_analysis` and it returned `True`
`print np.isscalar(annualized_sharpe_ratio)`

Comment: That's not how to debug it. First: the function in our comment took no input, second it's not the function called in minimize and third and most important: depending on your x0, shapes might get changed and your fake-tests might not reflect that. Therefore: add prints into the function itself before return something to minimize for debugging.

Comment: @sascha yeah..but even if I modify `sharpe` the function called in the minimizer as following:
`def sharpe(alloc, data):
    risk_free_annual_return = 0.08
    initial_capital = 307267
    sharepe_ratio = portfolio_analysis(data, alloc, initial_capital, risk_free_annual_return)
    print np.isscalar(sharepe_ratio)
    return sharepe_ratio`

It still says `True`. Also when we call the minimizer control doesnt go into the function `sharpe`.

Comment: Add an example we can run.

Comment: @sascha so it works now i think it was because of the `args` parameter and i removed that and moved the `dfstocks` to `portfolio_analysis` and that solved the problem. Thanks for your help.